# How to use html tags with ionic 2 action sheets?

Tags: html, ionic2

There was a option to use html tags with action sheets in ionic 1.

I tried the same in ionic 2 but no use.

Below is my code.

```
let actionSheet = this.actionSheetCtrl.create({
                title: '<b>Choose</b>',
                buttons: [
                  {}.......
```

Anyone done this?

Specifically i would like to add an image in the action sheet

Comment: are you trying to make it bold or is it a random example?

Comment: not only bold am trying to make use of html tags but not working, i just given sample

Comment: I dont think there is a provision for htm. but [check here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/action-sheet/ActionSheetController/) you can set cssClass option to customize if that is your requirement.

Comment: actually i want to display image next to that title so only i asked how to use html tags with action sheets

Answer (score 2):

No .. the title does not allow for a html string, nor do any of the other properties allow for html strings.

Your best bet is add a `cssClass` on the action sheet

```
let actionSheet = this.actionSheetCtrl.create({
            cssClass: 'title-img',
```

This will allow you to differentiate between any other action sheets you use and explicitly describe the css for maintainability.

You can then get sneaky with the css. So the main title class in the action sheet is  `.action-sheet-title`

So in order to add an image next to the title you just need to suffix the selector with `::before` or `::after`

for example

```
.title-img .action-sheet-title::before{ // if you want the image on the left of the title
    background:url('path-to-image-here') no-repeat;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}
```

That should work.