# Ionic4: Bottom sheet

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I want to display a `bottom sheet` with text and table.
`Action Sheet` is perfect in design but it does not allow to give HTML content.

Is there any way I can use the bottom sheet in Ionic4.

Below is a sample design

[image]

Comment: can you show image of what do you mean:https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-v4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fpages%2Faction-sheet%2Faction-sheet.component.ts

Comment: @לבנימלכה updated question with sample image

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use html tags with ionic 2 action sheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41734131/how-to-use-html-tags-with-ionic-2-action-sheets)

Comment: @לבנימלכה https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41734131/how-to-use-html-tags-with-ionic-2-action-sheets includes a background css image while my question has data and table to show. Can you please remove flag. Also Ionic4 is lot more different than Ionic2

Comment: but read what she/he said about insert html to action sheet

Comment: @לבנימלכה Yes I already read the solution. They are using css to solve the problem but I need data not css.  Please go and read the solution as well, I think you are just going through the question. Also Ionic4 is differently written hence Ionic2 solution won't work here.

Comment: Action sheet does not allow html you can see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/58134648/11999413

Comment: you can create model and code you want and the open to the bottom and the height 50% given then they actually look like bottom sheet