# Customization in Ionic Bottom Sheet

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-native

I am trying to add list in bottom sheet but ionic gave us an array so we can add class there and style it.
What i am trying to ask is how we can make a list or totally our own html code and pass it to bottom sheet function that will just display?

```
async presentActionSheet() {
    const actionSheet = await this.actionSheetController.create({
      header: 'Albums',
      buttons: [{
        text: 'Delete',
        role: 'destructive',
        icon: 'trash',
        handler: () => {
          console.log('Delete clicked');
        }
      }, {
        text: 'Share',
        icon: 'share',
        handler: () => {
          console.log('Share clicked');
        }
      }, {
        text: 'Play (open modal)',
        icon: 'arrow-dropright-circle',
        handler: () => {
          console.log('Play clicked');
        }
      }, {
        text: 'Favorite',
        icon: 'heart',
        handler: () => {
          console.log('Favorite clicked');
        }
      }, {
        text: 'Cancel',
        icon: 'close',
        role: 'cancel',
        handler: () => {
          console.log('Cancel clicked');
        }
      }]
    });
    await actionSheet.present();
  }
```

It is by default action sheet, what i want is to make it in DOM. I have found the similar question here with no answer [Similar Question URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54663521/ionic4-bottom-sheet)  Please see what i need...! 
[What i need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ejf28.png)

Comment: you can create model and code you want and the open to the bottom and the height 50% given then they actually look like bottom sheet

Comment: your comment is more helpful, i will try doing this.

Comment: this is not working please see the screenshot https://ibb.co/bWBy62j

Comment: its working well bro, because i implemented in my Project

Comment: my menu button hide behind it you can see my screenshort

Comment: i use recently in my project, i design input text and button added in model

Comment: Can you show me an example?

Comment: see below @Chandrakant Devani answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try with Modal Component

home.page.html

```
<ion-button (click)="OpenModel()">
    Open Modal (Bottom)
    <ion-icon mode="ios" name="arrow-forward"></ion-icon>
  </ion-button>
```

home.page.ts

```
import { ModalController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { ModalpagePage } from '../modalpage/modalpage.page';

constructor(private modalCtrl: ModalController) {}

  async OpenModel(){
    const presentModel = await this.modalCtrl.create({
      component: ModalpagePage,
      componentProps: {
        title: 'Billing Address',
        type:'billing',
      },
      showBackdrop: true,
      mode: "ios",
      cssClass: 'change-address-shipping-modal'
    });

    presentModel.onWillDismiss().then((data)=>{
      console.log(data);
      //custom code
    });

    return await presentModel.present();
  }
```

modalpage.page.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar text-center>
    <ion-title>
     Modal title
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content>

    <div>
      HTML CODE HERE
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

Declare in app.module.ts

```
declarations: [AppComponent, ModalpagePage],
  entryComponents: [ModalpagePage],
```

Global.scss

```
.change-address-shipping-modal{
    --height:60%;
    align-items: flex-end;
  }
```

ScreenShot

[image]

[image]

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-htjuyr)

Comment: How can I make the height adapt to the content size?

Comment: Have checked this Solution for Modal auto height ? 

https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/16852#issuecomment-449433452

Comment: Thanks a lot! Tried so long to find a solution but never stumbled upon this. using a combination of this and `cssClass: 'auto-height bottom-sheet'` for the bottom sheet with .bottom-sheet `{align-items: flex-end;}` gives me exactly what i want :)

Answer (score 0):

Currently action sheet does not allow you to add html code in it. This feature is however requested you can see here https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/16718

Comment: But there must be any other way to use template? or customize it

Comment: yes maybe some custom component would work but I didn't see any examples on internet about that.

Answer (score -1):

Try `<ion-card>`

```
<ion-header>  </ion-header>

<ion-content> </ion-content>

<ion-card> </ion-card> 

<ion-footer> </ion-footer>
```

you can use `*ngIf` to control `ion-card`

example:

in page.ts

```
showCard:Boolean = true;

constructor(){} 
ngOnInit() {}
```

in page.html

`<ion-card *ngIf="showCard"> </ion-card>`

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/card

Comment: it won't help, because its just hide and show the code

Comment: you should put `<ion-button expand="full"> </ion-button>` in `<ion-card>`