# Menu with icon on Ionic Action sheet

Tags: ionic-framework

Have a menu on Ionic action sheet and we need to set more two option to share the content, one icon to share using email and other whatsapp.

Has anyone made a menu with an icon like that?

[image]

Now, it is like this

[image]

The code

```
async menu(channelId: any, title: any) {
    const actionSheet = await this._ActionSheetController.create({
      backdropDismiss: false,
      header: title,
      buttons: [
        {
          icon: 'mail-outline',
          handler: () => {}
        },
        {
          icon: 'logo-whatsapp', 
          handler: () => {}
        },
        {
          text: this._TranslocoService.translate('channel.FollowedChannelsPage.stopFollowChannel'),
          icon: 'person-remove-outline',
          handler: () => {
            this.stopFollow(channelId)
          }
        },
        {
          text: this._TranslocoService.translate('others.close'),
          icon: 'close',
          role: 'destructive'
        }
      ]
    });
    await actionSheet.present();
  }
```

Comment: Share your Code and add more details.

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib I already updated the question

Comment: You can't achieve Horizontal Icons in Action Sheet. Try using Ionic Modal to achieve it. Check This: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58231133/5909026